# Bootstrap Ajax Form Crashes after Submitting

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap

i have created a Bootstrap Form with a ajax backend for sending and error handling.
After i have clicked the submit Button the whole site crashed and I have to restart the Browser.
Here the Code:
(Sorry but here teh Full code, i Do not know how to post the code)
http://codebin.org/view/54dd9fe1

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused by your architecture. Could you give us a little more info about what's on the server side and how that's implemented, and clarify what is on the client side (in the browser)? I'm happy to offer some comments but need more detail about what's happening.

Comment: Okay sorry :)
So, I tried the Script on different ways and on different architectures.
On my local Computer and on the Webserver with Apache I created the script in the link.
After clicking on the Button the forms should send to an E-Mail which is on the PHP Script "process.php", which is called in teh ajax part.
After the calling of the process.php side, the ajax function }).done(function(msg) {
                $( '#message' ).addClass( 'alert' );
                $( '#message' ).addClass( 'alert-success' );
                $( '#message').html( msg );
            });
Should display Sucess

Comment: The Problem is, after I click the Submit Button, the Whole Browser are freezing for 1 Minute. After that I got The message the i have to close the Browser.
I tried to use the COnsole on the Brwoser to watch, what is creating the error, but the Debug COnsole don't show anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could prevent form submitting and after ajax call you could submit the form.

You dont have to do this in `$( '#frmContact').submit( function()`

```
$().ready( function () {
    $("#bt").on("click",function(event){
    // prevent the submit of the form.
    event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

In your `HTML`

```
<button type="submit" id="bt" onclick="run();"
```

This `run function` has the `ajax` call and if `success` then `submit` form